# Pictonic Cube weird characters

Tags: mobile-website, webfonts

I'm using Pictonic Cube https://pictonic.co/ on a website. When I connect to the site through an "old" smartphone like Android 2.3 or Symbian I get weird characters like chinese characters or squares. What I'm doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect all versions of it's font. `.woff` is must have. Works almost everywhere. You can find some online utilties to make whole pack of nessecary fonts. Then just import it via CSS and sing the song.